# executemany() returns "can only execute DML statements"

Tags: python, sqlite

My query works for execute, but `executemany()` returns :

> ProgrammingError: executemany() can only execute DML statements.

The query :

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE firstname=:First AND lastname=:Last",ds[1].donor).fetchall()
```

vs. :

```
c.executemany("SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE firstname=:First AND lastname=:Last",[ds[1].donor,ds[2].donor]).fetchall()
```

Where `ds[i].donor` looks like `{'First': 'Cathy', 'Last': 'Lee'}`. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot `SELECT` with `executemany()`. DML stands for Data **Modification** Language, and a `SELECT` is not regarded as a modfication.

What you'll have to do is probably loop over the data:

```
for d in donors:
    cursor.execute("""
                   SELECT * FROM Donors
                   WHERE firstname=:First AND lastname=:Last
                   """, d.donor)
    print(cur.fetchall())
```

**Update: figured out it is, see update below!**
<del>Edit that I can't figure out yet</del> to make it copy-pastable:
You could also use the `IN(...)` operation, which should be something along the lines of:

```
cur.execute("""
            SELECT * FROM Donors
            WHERE firstname IN ({0})"""
            .format(', '.join(x.donor for x in donors)))
```

**Update for `IN` clauses:**

This is a worked example demonstrating how to use placeholders to dynamically construct a query with bound parameters, sparked by @olepinto's comment:

```py
import sqlite3

sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.set_trace_callback(print)

cur = con.execute("CREATE TABLE Donors(firstname, lastname, dob)")
data = (
    {"First": "Jane", "Last": "Doe", 'Dob': 1957},
    {"First": "John", "Last": "Doe", 'Dob': 1972},
    {"First": "John", "Last": "Bar", 'Dob': 1980},
    {"First": "Jane", "Last": "Foo", 'Dob': 1943},
)
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Donors VALUES(:First, :Last, :Dob)", data)
print("--- setup done ---", end="\n\n")

def format_with_in_clause(query, in_vals):
    # Interpolate the required number of placeholders
    return query + " IN ({0})".format(",".join(["?"] * len(in_vals)))

base_query = "SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE lastname"

# The happy path
params = ["Bar", "Foo"]
print("Happy path, all good:")
cur.execute(format_with_in_clause(base_query, params), (*params,))
print(cur.fetchall(), end="\n\n")

# DANGER: plain string interpolation is a pool of sharks :(
# Assume this is some user-input that is simply parsed into a list by upstream code
params = ["'') OR TRUE; --"] 
print("Oh dear, SQL injection at play:")
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE lastname IN (%s)" % params[0])
print(cur.fetchall(), end="\n\n")

# But bound parameters tame those sharks :)
params = ["'') OR TRUE; --"]
print("Bound parameters correctly escape the attacker's payload:")
cur.execute(format_with_in_clause(base_query, params), (*params,))
print(cur.fetchall(), end="\n\n")

# Also works for other data-types than string:
base_query = "SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE dob"
params = [1943, 1957]
print("Works with numbers:")
cur.execute(format_with_in_clause(base_query, params), (*params,))
print(cur.fetchall())
```

This outputs the following:

```plaintext
CREATE TABLE Donors(firstname, lastname, dob)
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Donors VALUES('Jane', 'Doe', 1957)
INSERT INTO Donors VALUES('John', 'Doe', 1972)
INSERT INTO Donors VALUES('John', 'Bar', 1980)
INSERT INTO Donors VALUES('Jane', 'Foo', 1943)
--- setup done ---

Happy path, all good:
SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE lastname IN ('Bar','Foo')
[('John', 'Bar', 1980), ('Jane', 'Foo', 1943)]

Oh dear, SQL injection at play:
SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE lastname IN ('') OR TRUE;
[('Jane', 'Doe', 1957), ('John', 'Doe', 1972), ('John', 'Bar', 1980), ('Jane', 'Foo', 1943)]

Bound parameters correctly escape the attacker's payload:
SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE lastname IN (''''') OR TRUE; --')
[]

Works with numbers:
SELECT * FROM Donors WHERE dob IN (1943,1957)
[('Jane', 'Doe', 1957), ('Jane', 'Foo', 1943)]
```

Comment: Putting query data into the sentences is not secure, it should be done using the `?` placeholder and passing the values as extra parameters. I haven't been able to do so, though, for a `IN` query.

Comment: @olepinto While what you say is absolutely true in essence, it doesn't apply here as it is already covered. [The sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders) state: "An SQL statement may use one of two kinds of placeholders: **question marks (qmark style)** or **named placeholders (named style)**". OP already had their parameters in named style, e.g., `:First` and `:Last`, so these are bound parameters and not interpolated strings. As to bound parameters and `IN`-clauses, see my recent update! :)